# Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment Found: com.marketing.auratek.chatapp.RequestsFragment

Tags: java, android-studio

I am making a chat app and created a new package. I have pasted the code below.
The Error is:
Required:android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Found:com.marketing.auratek.chatapp.RequestsFragmentcom.marketing.auratek.chatap

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Jagan on 7/14/2017.
 */

class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){

            case 0:
                RequestsFragment requestsFragment = new RequestsFragment();
                return requestsFragment;

            case 1:
                ChatsFragment chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
                return chatsFragment;

            case 2:
                FriendsFragment friendsFragment = new FriendsFragment();
                return friendsFragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```